# Algorithm to calculate exponent using recursion and mod

Tags: haskell, exponent

I was taught a different way to calculate exponents using mod and recursion, but I don't fully understand it. The method is: To do `b^e`, we can break it down like so:

```
  q = e div 2
  r = e mod 2
then e = 2q+r, and r could be 0 or 1.

If r=0:

    b^e = (b^q)^2

If r=1:

    b^e = (b^q)^2 * b

base case: b^0 = 1.
```

For example: `2^2, b=2, e=2`.

```
q = 2/2 = 1
r = 2mod2 = 0

r=0, therefore 2^2 = 2^1^2
```

I am trying to code this.

```
pow :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
pow b e
    | e == 0 = 1
    | r == 0 = pow (pow b q) 2
    | r == 1 = b * pow (pow b q) 2
  where
    (q, r) = divMod e 2
```

But the code does not end any time when `e!=0`, for example, `pow (-2) 4` or `pow 1 1` goes on forever. Any idea why?

Comment: Nope, no idea. Perhaps you should include the exact error -- and for that matter, the complete code that causes it, since this code on its own doesn't.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ok I edited the post to give a more precise error.

Comment: This is basically the same algorithm the base library uses to implement `(^)`, so you might want to look at [its source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#%5E).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try evaluating `pow b 2` by hand you'll quickly see why. Since `divMod 2 2 = (1, 0)`, we expand from `pow b 2` to `pow (pow b 1) 2`. Note that this is *also* of the form `pow b' 2`, with `b' = pow b 1`. So we just get an infinite chain:

```
pow b 2
=
pow (pow b 1) 2
=
pow (pow (pow b 1) 1) 2
=
pow (pow (pow (pow b 1) 1) 1) 2
=
...
```

There's a couple ways to solve it. You could add a base case for `e == 2`, or instead of recursively calling `pow` twice you could just do the multiplication yourself (as in replacing `pow foo 2` with `foo * foo` in your existing code).

Answer (score 2):

You also need to provide a base case for when `e` is `2`:

```
pow b 2 = b * b
```

Without this, your recursion doesn't end, because it becomes `pow (pow b 1) 2` and you don't get anywhere.

Comment: This could also be fixed by writing `let a = (pow b q) in a*a` instead of `pow (pow b q) 2`, which recurses too much.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous answers, your code *almost* works, and it is just a matter of allowing the recursion to stop.

See the code below for a possible fix. The argument of the recursive call is at most half the current argument, hence the recursion will have to stop.

On a side note, this algorithm is more than 2,000 years old, and originated in ancient India. Please treat it with all due respect :-)
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107708/origin-of-square-and-multiply-algorithm

```
pow :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
pow b e
    | e == 0 = 1
    | r == 0 = let bpq = pow b q  in  bpq*bpq
    | r == 1 = let bpq = pow b q  in  bpq*bpq*b
  where
    (q, r) = divMod e 2

main = do
    let b = 3 :: Integer
    let e = 7 :: Integer
    let x = b^e
    putStrLn ("b^e     = " ++ show x)
    let y = pow b e
    putStrLn ("pow b e = " ++ show y)
```